# Async Object doesn't register with get_it

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm using get_it for IoC. However, my app throws an exception when I try to register a bean using an async call.
The function that throws the exception:

```
import 'package:elpee/service/localstorage_service.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';


GetIt locator = GetIt();
Future setupLocator() async {
  LocalStorageService.getInstance().then((storageService) {
    locator.registerSingleton(storageService);
  });
}
```

The error:
`Exception: Object of type LocalStorageService is not registered inside GetIt`

If anyone could help me out, I'd greatly appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to use get_it wrong way. Check to [documentation](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/get_it).

First of all - get_it is Singleton, therefore don't use constructor, but

```
GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;
```

Second - implement LocalStorageService as a plain class and let the get_it to provide it as a Singleton:

```
void main()
...
   void setupLocator() {
     locator.registerLazySingleton(LocalStorageService());
   }
}
```

To use full power of IoC define interface / abstract class definition for your storageservice and provide implementation of the interface.

```
void setupLocator() {
  locator.registerLazySingleton<IStorageService>(LocalStorageService());
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I solved it a while back differently, but this solution looks better so I'll see if I can still benefit from it.

Comment: With GetIt version 4.0+ instance is created in the following way
GetIt.I.registerLazySingleton<Class>(() =>ClassImplementation());

Comment: Call setupLocator() in main() and start and stop your app in debug. Error should go away. Don't hot reload.